# Merge Proposal: Overdressing on the first day of work

Tags: discussion

I suggest merging this question:

[New Job, Casual Attire, First Impression](https://workplace.stackexchange.com/questions/31296/new-job-casual-attire-first-impression)

> I have accepted a new job at a particular company. The company has casual
>   attire (Jeans, T-Shirt). I have even seen some people wearing shorts
>   (I would pass on that!).
>
> Since, I will be joining as a new employee how I should be dressed for
>   2-3 months. Should I still wear formal attire (full sleeves with dress
>   pants).
>
> Also, how can I make a good impression as a new employee? I will be in
>   a senior level position and I will be responsible for training other
>   employees on certain technology.

Into the older:

[Should I err on the side of overdressing for my first day of work?](https://workplace.stackexchange.com/questions/10733/should-i-err-on-the-side-of-overdressing-for-my-first-day-of-work)

> I have accepte d a job offer as a software developer after two phone interviews, and
>   they told me that they have a relaxed dress code. Specifically, they
>   mentioned wearing jeans. However, I'm not sure whether that's jeans
>   with a polo, or a button-down shirt, or a T-shirt; and I want to
>   communicate on my first day that I take the job seriously. Is it
>   acceptable for me to show up on my first day in (nice) jeans
>   (particularly if I wear a nice shirt)? Is it a bigger risk for them to
>   wonder why I'm in jeans on my first day, or for them to feel like I'm
>   overdressed?

These questions seem to ask basically the same thing and have 6 answers each. Both refer to a workplace with full casual dress (jeans). I'm not entirely clear on the protocol for what the merged question's text should be but both can benefit from some rewording, presumably the post should be partially rewritten but that can be discussed if the merge has support.

If no consensus is reached in favour of a merge, at the very least the newest question should be closed as a duplicate and all future questions like this one redirected to the oldest question:

[Is it good to overdress more than the first day of work?](https://workplace.stackexchange.com/questions/59088/is-it-good-to-overdress-more-than-the-first-day-of-work)

Comment: I haven't reviewed the links yet, but from your quotes it looks like the first is asking about the first couple months (so, first day +), while the second asks specifically about the first day.  Do the answers reflect that difference too, or did everybody just end up talking about the first day?

Comment: @MonicaCellio Good catch. I thought they did, but it turns out it's the most recent question mentioned day 1 + first months. Of the more recent question, only 3 answers specify the timeframe. The others are general dress code answers that aren't specific to the first day/weeks. The older question is specific to the first day and answers there are assumed to cover that specific day, they don't expand beyond that.

Comment: Given that, perhaps the better option is to edit both questions to clarify the difference (first day versus first weeks) and redirect new duplicates accordingly: [this](http://workplace.stackexchange.com/questions/59088/is-it-good-to-overdress-more-than-the-first-day-of-work) one mentions the first months on the job so would redirect to the more recent question (first one linked in this question).

Comment: Editing to clearly differentiate, cross-linking where helpful, and marking dupes where they exist sounds like the right approach, then. Unfortunately we can't move answers, so if there are any answers on the "first few months" question that *only* talk about the first day, we can't migrate them.  On the other hand, if that's the case then they don't answer the whole question (and somebody could point that out in a comment and suggest answerinng the other question).